# python program with module os not working as intended

Tags: python

I am just starting to learn python and using it with my raspberry pi and GPIO. I am trying to program this so it runs this line "echo p >> /home/pi/.config/pianobar/ctl" which would pause the song that is playing. I got it to print it but it doesnt actually pause the song.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)
while True:
        mybutton = GPIO.input(11)
        if mybutton == False:
                print "pause"
                os.system("echo 'echo 'p' >> /home/pi/.config/pianobar/ctl'")
                time.sleep(.2)
```

and the output is: echo p >> /home/pi/.config/pianobar/ctl

pause

but nothing actually happens.

Comment: Have you tried running that in the shell at all? Note that your quotes are not balanced, you cannot just nest `'` inside other `'` quotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters when i run echo 'p' >> /home/pi/.config/pianobar/ctl in the terminal it pauses the song. how do i need to put the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
os.system("echo 'echo 'p' >> /home/pi/.config/pianobar/ctl'")
```

has two `echo`s, and the `>>` operator is quoted, so all it's doing is printing something to standard output. Try:

```
os.system("echo 'p' >> /home/pi/.config/pianobar/ctl")
```